# How to make force npm to install deprecated packages?

Tags: react-native, npm, package-managers

I've recently joined to a team and cloned the project and tried to install it. It's a react native project.

`npm install` fails. So that I've tried to install packages one by one manually. Few first packages installed as well, but this package `npm i @react-native-community/picker` throws the following error:

[image]

I guess the issue is because of the package depreciation. Any idea how can I force npm to install it anyway? (I cannot change that package, because the project is using it inside the codebase)

Noted that I've the following node version installed (and I can change them using `nvm`):

- `*` 16.15.1 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
- 14.16.0
- 12.9.1
- 10.15.2
- 8.16.2

Answer (score 0):

> You can try below command to force install:

```
npm install --force
```